# Remote method doesn't show up in loopback API explorer

Tags: javascript, node.js, loopbackjs

I have a role-mapping model which maps a userId to a roleId, I need a remote method on the role-mapping model to retrieve the role-mappingId for a given userId.

this the code for the remoteMethod

```
'use strict';

module.exports = function(Rolemapping) {
   Rolemapping.getRolesByUser = async function (id, cb) {
    const roleMappings = await Rolemapping.find({ where: { principalId: id 
 } })
    cb(null, roleMappings);
  };
  Rolemapping.remoteMethod("getRolesByUser", {
    http: {
      path: "/getRolesByUser",
      verb: "get"
    },
    accepts: [
      { arg: "userId", type: "string", http: { source: "query" } }
    ],
    returns: {
      arg: "result",
      type: "string"
    },
    description: "Cvs "
  });
 };
```

this is the role-mapping json file :

```
{
  "name": "roleMapping",
  "base": "RoleMapping",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
  "validateUpsert": true
},
   "properties": {},
   "validations": [],
   "relations": {
   "role": {
   "type": "belongsTo",
   "model": "role",
   "foreignKey": "roleId"
 }
 },
   "acls": [],
   "methods": {}
 }
```

the above remote method doesn't show up in the loopback API explorer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RoleMapping` is a built-in model, its `role-mapping.js` file is hidden in `node_modules/loopback`, I've tested it and it doesn't look like will load a js file for itself from `common/models`.

It looks like a boot script is your only option.  It's the same code, but your function receives the server object.

`server/boot/get-roles-by-user.js`

```
module.exports = function(server) {
  const Rolemapping = server.models.RoleMapping;
  Rolemapping.getRolesByUser = async function (id) {
    return JSON.stringify(await Rolemapping.find({ where: { principalId: id
      } }))
  };
  Rolemapping.remoteMethod("getRolesByUser", {
    http: {
      path: "/getRolesByUser",
      verb: "get"
    },
    accepts: [
      { arg: "userId", type: "string", http: { source: "query" } }
    ],
    returns: {
      arg: "result",
      type: "string"
    },
    description: "Cvs "
  });
}
```

I've also removed the `cb` parameter from your remote method, because methods which return a `Promise` do not need it, just return the value like you would for any other function